# "Unable to resolve host no Address associated with hostname" While trying to connect ftp host through FtpClient()

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, ftp-client

```
        val file = File(localFilePath)
        val ftpClient = FTPClient()
        ftpClient.connectTimeout = 100*1000
       // ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress))
        ftpClient.connect(serverAddress)
        ftpClient.login(userName, password)
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(folderPath)
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        success = ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFileName, inputStream)
        inputStream.close()
```

This is my code to connect and upload image into the folder in server.
result - unable to resolve host while trying in android but able to connect and push images into server through webclient.

Comment: Show how serverAddress looks like.

Comment: Please place that between ticks so we see the whole string. And without a link. We dont need a link. And we wanna see a protocol if there is.

Comment: That is not between ticks. We see nothing and you produced a link. `ftp://waws-prod-bay-177.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/` is between ticks. Now we see the protocol and know what you do.

Comment: You should remove the `ftp://` from it.